# Select @@Identity returning 0 for linked table in Access

Tags: mysql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using Access 2007 and have some linked tables to a mySQL database.  I am using DAO to insert a record into a mySQL linked table and trying to retrieve the inserted PK using Select @@identity, but that select is returning 0.

```
  Dim sql As String

  Dim oDB As Database
  Set oDB = CurrentDb 

  sql = "INSERT INTO Quotes ( CustomerID ) SELECT 1 AS Expr1;" 

  oDB.Execute sql 

  If oDB.RecordsAffected <> 1 Then 
    MsgBox "cannot create new quote"
    Exit Function
  End If

  Dim rsNewID As DAO.Recordset
  Set rsNewID = oDB.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")  ' Create a recordset and SELECT the new Identity

  Dim intNewID As Long
  intNewID = rsNewID(0).Value ' Store the value of the new identity in variable intNewID
  'This value is 0, why?
```

I've seen [another question like this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186544/identity-after-insert-statement-always-returns-0) that has not been satisfactorily answered for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fredrik gets partial credit, for the mySQL statement.  It's important to note that I am using DAO, so statements are processed by the JET engine and it does not support this statement.  This needs to be run as a pass through query in Access in order to work though.  After I made a pass through query with fredrik's select statement, that did the trick.  I called this Access passthrough query from my DAO code and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

Comment: For some reason this is not working from Access.  I don't think Access can use backend functions in a query if it is not a PassThrough query.  It tells me it cannot find the function "Last_Insert_ID()"

Answer (score 0):

I have not used mysql. So, translate what I say for mysql.

Is CustomerID an identity column (i.e. does it generate ID on its own)?
If so, use the function that returns the last generated ID.

@@Identity function is what people use in SQL Server. I don''t know of equivalent in mysql.
See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-insert-id.html)

Looking at the code above, you need not open the 2nd recordset. The `rsNewID1` should help you get the last inserted ID.

Hope this helps.