# Using @@Identity

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm wondering how I could get the most recently generated autonumber value from a table in another db. Currently I am doing this:

```vb
Do Until rsA.EOF
    'Inserts new row here (works)
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset 
    rs.Open "SELECT @@Identity" (Connection info)
    SQLcmd = "UPDATE tbl SET col = " & rs("SELECT @@Identity").Value & " 
    (WHERE statement);"
    DoCmd.RunSQL SQLcmd
    rsA.MoveNext
Loop
```

But its giving col a value of 0 instead of the newly generated autonumber. 
Any idea why? Or another way to do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/186544/11683

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show the code which does the `INSERT` into the other database.  If you're using the `Execute` method of an ADO Connection object to do that, run the `SELECT @@Identity` query from that *same connection object* ... not a new connection with the same connection string.  `@@Identity` is only usable within the same connection session; otherwise you'll get 0.

And actually you don't even need a recordset to capture that value.  If your connection object is named `conn`, this will return a recordset, but you need not assign it to a recordset object variable.  Simply ask for the first item from the returned recordset.

```
Debug.Print "most recent autonumber: " & _
    conn.Execute("SELECT @@Identity")(0)
```

Comment: +1 Beat me to it.  As @HansUp states, the key is to use the same *connection*, not simply the same connection string.

Comment: I'm using a SQL INSERT INTO SELECT statement. 
When I run conn.Execute(...) it returns 0.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem if you're executing the `INSERT` from an ADO connection object, and you later `SELECT @@Identity` from that same connection object.  The code in my answer was tested in Access 2007.  I didn't show the `INSERT`, but I can if it helps.

Comment: I was saving the command as a string and using runcmd.runSQL. Will that not work?

Comment: `RunSQL` does not use the ADO connection.  Most likely you're getting 0 as the last identity value from the *current* database ... not from the other db you're inserting into.

Comment: I've used the @@IDENTITY all the time too. Recently, one of my coworker told me that I should never use the @@IDENTITY. He said that I should instead used know values and do a select statement from the proper table. The @@IDENTITY has been working fine for me. Is it really bad to use the @@IDENTITY?

Comment: This is a great single-line example of how to get @@Identity with ADO.   The simple method for DAO is `CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@IDENTITY")(0)`