# In access create a row using only default values

Tags: ms-access

I want a new entry created in table Moments using the predefined defaults for each field.

I've tried the following lines and I'm getting a syntax error for both. What would be the correct method to do this in Access?

```
INSERT INTO Moments VALUES ()

Access highlights the end bracket after clicking ok on syntax error.
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Moments () VALUES ()

Access highlights the first bracket after clicking ok on syntax error.
```

and

```
INSERT INTO Moments default values

Access highlights default after clicking ok on syntax error.
```

Comment: Does it have to be a query? You can easily do this using VBA.

Comment: No it does not have to be a query. How would you go about doing it in VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBA, this can easily be achieved with recordsets:

```vb
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Moments") 'Open table
rs.AddNew 'Add row
rs.Update 'Commit to table
```

Comment: How would you get the id of the record newly created?

Comment: That's a different question. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17931268/7296893). Alternatively, you can use `rs.MoveLast` and then `rs!ID` (if `ID` is your id column)

Comment: `rs.Bookmark = rs.LastModified` -- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195859.aspx @Tolure